# Can we dynamically invoke a Java interface method with a generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics

The following code compiles and works fine.  I defined a Builder interface, then the CarBuilder class is used to handle anything related to a Car, and the BusBuilder class is used to handle anything related to a Bus.  Car and Bus share an abstract class named Vehicle.  The code is straightforward.  The code will output:

```
do something to CREATE the Car
do something to UPDATE the Car
do something to CREATE the Bus
do something to UPDATE the Bus
```

Here is the original code that compiles:

```
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Car extends Vehicle { }
public class Bus extends Vehicle { }

public interface Builder<V extends Vehicle> {
    public V createVehicle(String spec);
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, Vehicle vehicle);
}

public class CarBuilder implements Builder<Car> {
    public Car createVehicle(String spec) {
        Car car = new Car();
        System.out.println("do something to CREATE the Car");
        return car;
    }
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, Vehicle vehicle) {
        Car car = (Car) vehicle;
        System.out.println("do something to UPDATE the Car");
        return;
    }
}

public class BusBuilder implements Builder<Bus> {
    public Bus createVehicle(String spec) {
        Bus bus = new Bus();
        System.out.println("do something to CREATE the Bus");
        return bus;
    }
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, Vehicle vehicle) {
        Bus bus = (Bus) vehicle;
        System.out.println("do something to UPDATE the Bus");
        return;
    }
}

@Test
public void main() {
    Builder<? extends Vehicle> builder = null;
    Vehicle vehicle = null;

    builder = new CarBuilder();
    vehicle = builder.createVehicle("my original Car spec");
    builder.updateVehicle("my modified Car spec", vehicle);

    builder = new BusBuilder();
    vehicle = builder.createVehicle("my original Bus spec");
    builder.updateVehicle("my modified Bus spec", vehicle);
}
```

But, I'd like to make my code even more strongly-typed.  I want to change the interface method,

from

```
public void updateVehicle(String spec, Vehicle vehicle);
```

to

```
public void updateVehicle(String spec, V vehicle);
```

In other words, I tried to use generic `V` instead of base class `Vehicle` in my interface signature.  This forces the implementors of `Builder` to "close" on the specific product type (i.e. either `Car` or `Bus`, but not the base class `Vehicle`).   `CarBuilder` shall only handle a `Car`; `BusBuilder` should only handle a `Bus`.

The code becomes as follows:

```
public interface Builder<V extends Vehicle> {
    public V createVehicle(String spec);
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, V vehicle);
}

public class CarBuilder implements Builder<Car> {
    public Car createVehicle(String spec) {
        Car car = new Car();
        System.out.println("do something to CREATE the Car");
        return car;
    }
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, Car car) {
        System.out.println("do something to UPDATE the Car");
        return;
    }
}

public class BusBuilder implements Builder<Bus> {
    public Bus createVehicle(String spec) {
        Bus bus = new Bus();
        System.out.println("do something to CREATE the Bus");
        return bus;
    }
    public void updateVehicle(String spec, Bus bus) {
        System.out.println("do something to UPDATE the Bus");
        return;
    }
}

@Test
public void main() {
    Builder<? extends Vehicle> builder = null;
    Vehicle vehicle = null;

    builder = new CarBuilder();
    vehicle = builder.createVehicle("my original Car spec");
    builder.updateVehicle("my modified Car spec", vehicle);  <== compilation error

    builder = new BusBuilder();
    vehicle = builder.createVehicle("my original Bus spec");
    builder.updateVehicle("my modified Bus spec", vehicle);  <== compilation error
}
```

Two compilation errors - Java compiler won't allow this because "**The method updateVehicle(String, capture#3-of ? extends Vehicle) in the type Builder is not applicable for the arguments (String, Vehicle)**".

In Java is there a way to do what I want to accomplish?  In C# I can simply type my variable with **var** keyword, like `var vehicle` instead of `Vehicle vehicle`.  I heard that Java generics invocation is a compile-time decision.  Is there a technique to overcome this?

Comment: Why wouldn't the method for updating something about a bus or car be in that respective class?

Comment: Makes sense yes. A Builder is most commonly used to create an instance, not to update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an idiom, called [a capture helper,](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/#3.0) that helps in cases like this.

Essentially, given your declaration of `builder`, all the compiler knows is that `vehicle` is something that extends `Vehicle`. Further, it knows that `Builder` requires some specific type of `Vehicle` passed to its `updateVehicle()` method. The compiler is unable to draw the inference that is obvious to us—that the type is compatible. To do that, we have to get rid of the wildcard by using a helper method.

A practical application to real code is not obvious from your simple test harness. But, applying it in this context would look something like the following. Hopefully this example will be enough to illustrate the idea and help you apply it to real code.

```
public void main()
{
  Builder<? extends Vehicle> builder;
  Vehicle vehicle;

  builder = new CarBuilder();
  vehicle = createAndUpdateHelper(builder, "my original Car spec", "my modified Car spec");

  builder = new BusBuilder();
  vehicle = createAndUpdateHelper(builder, "my original Bus spec", "my modified Bus spec");
}

private static <V extends Vehicle> V createAndUpdateHelper(Builder<V> builder, String s1, String s2)
{
  V v = builder.createVehicle(s1);
  builder.updateVehicle(s2, v);
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense : you want your builders to only accept a Car or a Bus (which is fine), but then you give them an instance of Vehicle. You're doing the exact thing you're trying to prevent : accept the generic class Vehicle.

Comment: I had to type my variable with `Vehicle` because there isn't any other way to do that in Java.  Like I mentioned in C# I can type it with `var` which preserves runtime type - my variable `vehicle` at runtime holds either a Car or a Bus.  I guess it comes down to the fact that Java generics invocation decision was designed to be made at compile-time so there isn't other facility to get around it.

Comment: Well, considering that you're doing new CarBuilder() at line i and then call it to create a vehicle at line i+1 you can safely give the type Car to your newly created Vehicle.

Comment: In my real project, the Builder instance is injected so after I call create() I can't type it to either Car or Bus.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method would be to filter input that doesn't match expected or desired input.

```
if(vehicle instanceof Car) return;
```

A more thorough (and less brittle) implementation can be created by using enums to control various aspects of the car (Type, Color). You can then use a single Builder with switches to handle any combination thereof. (I have some example code written up for this, if you need it then feel free to shoot me a message and I will send you a copy)

Comment: It would work yes, but he's intent is to have a strongly typed code, not receive failures at runtime (instead of returning I would throw an IllegalArgumentException or something like that).

Comment: Well said vtheron. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @vtheron I completely agree, but if simplicity was an objective then that is the easiest way to fix potential problems. Give me a moment I am writing up the best (in my opinion) way to handle this now.